# Recognize an absolute web URL even without a scheme

Tags: java, regex, url, url-scheme, absolute-path

I am working on a Java method that differentiates between absolute and relative URLs the way a browser address bar would rather than the way a strict URL parser would. That is, I want it to recognize a URL as absolute if it starts with a host,
whether or not the scheme is present. That way, it correctly recognizes scheme-relative URLs (like `//example.com`) and URLs with the scheme completely omitted (like `example.com`, `wikipedia.org`, `lots.and-lots.of.domains.com.ng`). The method I', currently using looks something like this

```java
public String checkPossiblyAbsolute(String url) {
    if (url.matches("^(\\/\\/)?([-_A-Za-z0-9]+\\.)+\\w{2,3}(\\/.*)?$")) {
        if (url.startsWith("//")) url = "http:" + url;
        else url = "http://" + url;
    }
    return url;
}
```

Basically, it checks for dot separated sequences of the characters `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, `-`, and `_` where the last sequence (the TLD) contains exactly 2 or 3 letters. Also, the string may start with an optional `//`. My tests work the way I expected, but I really want to find an easier (or at least more readable) way to do this. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Java does not allow you to avoid double escaping things. (Some languages allow `@"une\scapedRegex"`).

There are some modifications you can make to the regex syntax, however.

- `\\.` can become `[.]` Not shorter, but IMHO more readable.
- Same with `\\/`. Make it `[/]`.
- You can get rid of `A-Z` if you use case insensitive mode. May not be worth it when you have only one `A-Z`.

---

There's not much more you can do, except put things in variables. Again, may not be worth it if you have only a few redundancies, but it could improve readability. You're using Java, so you're not winning code-golf, anyways.